# Mondrian : how to restrict drill-through in a cell?

Tags: mondrian

Assume I have a Mondrian Cube about sales in different countries. I want everybody to be able to see the amount of sales in every country.
But when a user, say the manager of sales in Europa, wants to drill-through in a cell in order to see the details for the sales of a specific country, I want to disable this drill-through if he has no right for this country : in my example, the manager of sales in Europa could drill-through in the cells France, Belgium, and so on, but not in the cells Japan, China,... although he can see the global amount of sales for those countries.

Is there a way to do that?

Thank you

Benoit

**Edited on november 18 :**

I have restricted the access via bottomlevel as suggested : as the joined picture shows it, it disables the expanding of the dimension "Markets", but the user can still drill-through a cell and see the detail in the bottom table of the report.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set up access control based on roles.

One way is setting the European Manager role with no access to the All Countries member, then explicitly granting him access to Europe. Granting access to a member automatically grants access to its children, unless you explicitly deny it later.

See http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/schema.php#Access_control and be careful, order of grants matters (there are a few examples in the documentation that ilustrate that).

Comment: Thank you, but what I want to achieve is not to restrict the drill-in but the drill-through in a cell in order to restrict access to "source data" e.g. the details of orders or client identity, although he could see the number of orders by region. The answer on the Pentaho's forum is rather negative : http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?176216-Limiting-drill-through-in-cells-Pentaho-CE-5-2&s=f7c7e60ef8f05430c5b92e44ee0dcdfe&p=393305#post393305

Comment: You can set both a topLevel and a bottomLevel in any dimension. Regardless of what members are granted or denied, you cannot see below the bottomLevel.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it as soon as possible. Thank you @nsousa